# How to format Date in Python that is retrieve from a table?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code where I'm writing my data into a file. How do I convert my dob variable into a different date format. 
Dob Currently shoes up in the file as: 2020-04-30 00:00:00  but I want it to show as 4/30/2020. Any suggestions?

```
    with open(r"C:\inetpub\ftproot\mhv\mhv_exportdetail.txt",'w') as f:
    for companyrow in company_rows:
        # Joining the ints,and strings in the tuple to convert to a string
        newRow = '\t'.join(map(str,companyrow))
        #print(newRow)

        dob  =(companyrow[12])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

oldformat = '2020-04-30 00:00:00'
dob = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (dob)
```

prints:

```
04/30/2020
```

Comment: I get this error:           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\Mhv_FtpExport.py", line 91, in <module>
    newformat = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>>

Comment: Can you post a sample date that fails, maybe it's not exactly the format you specified?

Comment: So I read my example date from a table. I call it dob I see it in the table when I print it out the same exact format 2020-04-30 00:00:00                                                                                                          'oldformat = str(dob)
            print(oldformat)
            newformat = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y') '

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
from datetime import datetime

previous_datetime = "2020-04-30 00:00:00"
new_datetime = datetime.strptime(previous_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(new_datetime)
```

Which will output:

```
04/30/2020
```

I would recommend learning the [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), as they can prove very useful.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\Mhv_FtpExport.py", line 91, in <module>
    newformat = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>>      This the error I get